# _main undefined during link from cython

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython

I am attempting to produce a binary from a minimal Python file:

```py
print 'hello'
```

Using this makefile:

```make
#!/usr/bin/make -f

export

flags=
cflags=$(flags) $(shell python-config --cflags)
ldflags=$(flags) $(shell python-config --ldflags)

all: multi

.PRECIOUS: %.o %.c

multi: multi.o makefile
    gcc -o $@ $< $$ldflags

%.o: %.c makefile
    gcc -o $@ $< $$cflags -c

%.c: %.py makefile
    cython $<
```

Nothing special... but I get:

```
$ make
cython multi.py
gcc -o multi.o multi.c $cflags -c
multi.c:1318:28: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyObject_AsString' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE char* __Pyx_PyObject_AsString(PyObject* o) {
                           ^
multi.c:1315:32: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyUnicode_FromString' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject* __Pyx_PyUnicode_FromString(const char* c_str) {
                               ^
multi.c:308:29: warning: unused function '__Pyx_Py_UNICODE_strlen' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE size_t __Pyx_Py_UNICODE_strlen(const Py_UNICODE *u)
                            ^
multi.c:1380:26: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyObject_IsTrue' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_PyObject_IsTrue(PyObject* x) {
                         ^
multi.c:1430:33: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyIndex_AsSsize_t' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE Py_ssize_t __Pyx_PyIndex_AsSsize_t(PyObject* b) {
                                ^
multi.c:1455:33: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyInt_FromSize_t' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject * __Pyx_PyInt_FromSize_t(size_t ival) {
                                ^
multi.c:1033:32: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyInt_From_long' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject* __Pyx_PyInt_From_long(long value) {
                               ^
multi.c:1080:27: warning: function '__Pyx_PyInt_As_long' is not needed and will not be emitted [-Wunneeded-internal-declaration]
static CYTHON_INLINE long __Pyx_PyInt_As_long(PyObject *x) {
                          ^
multi.c:1175:26: warning: function '__Pyx_PyInt_As_int' is not needed and will not be emitted [-Wunneeded-internal-declaration]
static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_PyInt_As_int(PyObject *x) {
                         ^
9 warnings generated.
multi.c:1318:28: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyObject_AsString' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE char* __Pyx_PyObject_AsString(PyObject* o) {
                           ^
multi.c:1315:32: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyUnicode_FromString' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject* __Pyx_PyUnicode_FromString(const char* c_str) {
                               ^
multi.c:308:29: warning: unused function '__Pyx_Py_UNICODE_strlen' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE size_t __Pyx_Py_UNICODE_strlen(const Py_UNICODE *u)
                            ^
multi.c:1380:26: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyObject_IsTrue' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_PyObject_IsTrue(PyObject* x) {
                         ^
multi.c:1430:33: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyIndex_AsSsize_t' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE Py_ssize_t __Pyx_PyIndex_AsSsize_t(PyObject* b) {
                                ^
multi.c:1455:33: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyInt_FromSize_t' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject * __Pyx_PyInt_FromSize_t(size_t ival) {
                                ^
multi.c:1033:32: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyInt_From_long' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject* __Pyx_PyInt_From_long(long value) {
                               ^
multi.c:1080:27: warning: function '__Pyx_PyInt_As_long' is not needed and will not be emitted [-Wunneeded-internal-declaration]
static CYTHON_INLINE long __Pyx_PyInt_As_long(PyObject *x) {
                          ^
multi.c:1175:26: warning: function '__Pyx_PyInt_As_int' is not needed and will not be emitted [-Wunneeded-internal-declaration]
static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_PyInt_As_int(PyObject *x) {
                         ^
9 warnings generated.
gcc -o multi multi.o $ldflags
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
     (maybe you meant: ___pyx_module_is_main_multi)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [multi] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to build an executable, where cython is meant to create python-extensions. Thus the Python interpreter's main would be used.

The documentation explicitly states that your approach of using cython without distutils is for debugging purposes. Use distutils instead, as documented in the tutorial, and then import your module to execute code.

Alternatively, link your object-files with the Python DLL/so, and add a main-function yourself.

Comment: My main objective is performance, rather than independent distribution capability. So how would I modify this to build, presumably, a dylib (OSX) and then invoke it from Python?

Comment: As it's described in the tutorial. http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html

Comment: Here's a short list of things I hate:

- The "Setup" file. Currently it's being silently ignored when I try to use it to pass compiler switches. Why this doesn't exist as a part of setup.py, I have no idea.
- How opaque and arcane the setup.py process is. There are two or three invisible layers of abstraction between the compiler and me.
- The fact that "-dynamic", "-bundle" and "-undefined" are undocumented in the OSX cc.

Comment: I agree that distutils isn't exactly amazing. However with that trivial hello-world of yours, I fail to see any of the customizations you seem to anticipate as necessary. And my personal approach would be "let python & cython do, what they do best", and for my C/C++-code I'd resort to building static libraries the aforementioned would just link to. Thus you have the control you want over the code you write. Which IMHO is pointless for the generated code of Cython.